# Which is better Magento or a php custom build?

Tags: php, custom, security

Am planing to run a business and i have two option to choose between Magento or Php custom build (both of them will have the same functionality) so am considering about **STABILITY** and about **SECURITY**.
impatiently waiting for your advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comparing Magento and a custom build is like comparing a program written in C# and another written in assembly. The first option is a HUGE time saver, compared to very few (and often nonexistent benefits).

People have worked countless hours developing the platform functionality, stability and security, which would be very hardly equaled by a custom build.

I would advise you to use Magento and build around it customization based on your needs.

Answer (score 0):

obviously Magento is custom built :)
Your custom built shopping cart will have twice more vulnerabilities than in Magento, and some of them you will never know about and wont be able to fix ever.